# How to use the .NET 4.5 Owin to Authenticate with LinkedIn

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, linkedin-api

.NET 4.5 now has these different ways to authenticate, but I do not see one for LinkedIn. Does anyone have any idea if .NET 4.5 has a built in way to oAuth with LinkedIn?

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;

namespace WebPageStarterKit
{
    public partial class Startup {

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301883
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and also store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider.
            // This is required if your application allows users to login
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
            //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            //    clientId: "",
            //    clientSecret: "");

            //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
            //   consumerKey: "",
            //   consumerSecret: "");


            //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            //   appId: "",
            //   appSecret: "");

            //app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be extraordinary if someone could be so kind to bless this community with a solution to my questions.

Comment: do you want to validate with twitter, or do more (post, etc)?

Comment: I'm just concerned about LinkedIN

Comment: use nuget to get the full range of Owin.Security.Providers https://github.com/owin-middleware/OwinOAuthProviders

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about "built in"... but you can use nuget to get another OWIN package.

Check out this site [Introducing the Yahoo and LinkedIn OAuth security providers for OWIN](http://www.beabigrockstar.com/blog/introducing-the-yahoo-linkedin-oauth-security-providers-for-owin/) for a pretty straightfoward tutorial.

In a nutshell:

1. Use nuget to install this package: Owin.Security.Providers
2. Sign up for LinkedIn developer account at [LinkedIn Developers](http://developer.linkedin.com)
3. Request the API keys. Make note of the API key and Secret Key when you finish filling in the form
4. Edit your App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs file to include "using Owin.Security.Providers.Linkedin"
5. At the bottom of that file, add in a section for LinkedIn:

   ```
       app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions() 
       {
           ClientId = "API Key",
           ClientSecret = "Secret Key",
       });
   ```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.